# How can i create a local highscore list - Android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i'm starting to finish up an app I've been working on for a while and i was wondering whats a good way to implement a highscore list of let's say the top 25 highscores with 2 columns(name,score).  I was thinking of a listview possibly but im not sure how to make it not take up the whole screen. Any better ideas and suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT:
How do i implement a framelayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a ListView in a ViewGroup (such as a linearlayout or framelayout) to make it take a portion of the screen or share it.

You will also need to put the scores somewhere that persists, SharedPreferences, a Database, a file.

I typically serialize to JSON, simplest method for me.

Comment: ive been saving and loading from a text file, is that alright?

Comment: Whatever is easiest for you is alright. If it meets your requirements and works reliably, then it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

ListView is always a good idea if you want to display same views (esp TextView) in a list. Are you also considering to upload scores online.

Comment: so how  would i draw a listview inside my custom views game over screen? and yes i am i think im gonna use scoreninja for that

Comment: You mean, you want to display the listview over the paused game screen? If thats the case, you can start a new activity containing listview with Theme.Dialog

Comment: what i want is when the player loses the endgame screen pops up on the bottom half of the screen i want a list that scrolls so you can look at all the highscores